# rotate camera LookAt point

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Using a glm::lookAt function to create the camera view matrix is good but does not help in storing the camera Euler angles. although the calculations seem correct, the view seems to bring the wrong pitch value.

in the following code, if the Y values of the current camera position and destination is the same then, there is no problem. however, the view seems to tilt further down or up if the Y values of the camera position and destination are not equal.
The question is: why does the camera not correctly points an object if the Y values of the camera and object positions are not equal.

```
    float wrapAngle(float angle)
    {
      int break_after = 100;
      constexpr float full_rotation = 2.0 * glm::pi<float>();
      while (angle < 0.0f || angle >= full_rotation)
      {
        if (angle < 0.0f) angle = angle + full_rotation;
        if (angle >= full_rotation) angle = angle - full_rotation;
        if (--break_after == 0) break;
      }
      if (break_after == 0) angle = 0.0f;
      return angle;
    }

    void getLookAtAngle(const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec3& destination, glm::vec3 &angle)
    {
      //! Find vector of sight toward destination.
      glm::vec3 sight = destination - position;

      //! Find X, Y rotation against the axis (global).
      double yAngle = wrapAngle(std::atan2(sight.x, sight.z));

      glm::mat4 yModel(1);
      yModel = glm::rotate(yModel, static_cast<float>(-yAngle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1, 0));
      sight = yModel * glm::vec4(sight, 1.0f);

      double xAngle = wrapAngle(-std::atan2(sight.y, sight.z));

      //! assign xAngle, yAngle to the parameter 'angle'
      angle.x = glm::degrees(static_cast<float>(xAngle));
      angle.y = glm::degrees(static_cast<float>(yAngle));
      angle.z = 0.0f;
    }

    void updateCamera(const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec3& destination)
    {
      glm::vec3 m_rotation(1);
      getLookAtAngle(position, destination, m_rotation)
      m_model = glm::mat4(1);
      m_model = glm::rotate(m_model, glm::radians(m_rotation[0]), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0));
      m_model = glm::rotate(m_model, glm::radians(m_rotation[1]), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1, 0));
      m_model = glm::rotate(m_model, glm::radians(m_rotation[2]), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0, 1));
      m_front = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(m_model * glm::vec4(0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f)));
      m_right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_front, glm::vec3(0, 1.0f, 0)));
      m_up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_right, m_front));
      m_view = glm::lookAt(position, position+ m_front, m_up);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the Euler angles?

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the question here. What is it you want to achieve? In general (whichever tool you use) when rotating in 1st person perspective you have 2 very common situations which differ in result. One will allow tilting and the other will do a correction so that Y will seem to always point upwards. So the first one is used in for instance airplane simulation and the second one is in some first person shooter. It is hard to tell but what you are saying seems like you made the first solution but want the second result.

Comment: do you mean that is for flight mode then use     m_view = glm::lookAt(position, position, m_up); and for first shooter mode then use   m_view = glm::lookAt(position, position+ m_front, m_up);